# Chosing a right framework

Tags: java, gwt, frameworks, open-source

I am planning to develop a web application using GWT, but before that I need to make few clarifications. The web app what I am developing should be compatible with Mobile phone browsers considerable smart phone browsers.

I googled a lot to know this but I did not find supporting or sufficient documentations.

If GWT doesnt support what would be the other framework, which is open source java based framework?

Comment: Any of the major web frameworks are being used with GWT.  I'm a big fan of Struts 2, Spring MVC has a very good following too. Your friend here is google.  Read for a while and see if you can find the support you need for GWT with your framework of interest.  Here a a good list of frameworks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no big problem with mobile websites build using GWT, it generates standard javascript + html. There is some libraries that can help you build mobile site, like http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/. And you can write any widget you wish.

But keep in mind that GWT will generate very heavy target files, sometimes few megabytes long. So if you target audience uses GPRS for accessing your site, it could be problematic for them.

There is also other web-framework, that are GWT based: http://vaadin.com/home.
It have great collection of UI components, and currently authors are extending it to be more mobile friendly.

Comment: Or you could use GWT split points so that mobile user dont have to load your full application before starting using it 

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CodeSplitting

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a different route with [Context Framework](http://www.contextfw.net). I think it suites better to mobile web developing because it is more lightweight solution. I have made a journey planner (in Finnish) with it and it was tailored especially to touch screen phones. You can find it [here](http://www.contextfw.net/reittiopas).